# What martial art uses vambrace/bracelet or forearms for a fighting technique?

Tags: kung-fu, style, identification

I remember there's an Asian martial arts technique (especially China, and I believe India also has it but I don't know which tag to use for that) that solely uses their forearms for strikes and blocks as their primary technique. Usually wearing [vambrace](https://acc-cdn.azureedge.net/mrl-live-media-file/0000089_steel-vambraces_550.jpeg)/bracelet as their weapons, here is the [Asian military bronze vambrace](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b0/55/ac/b055ace1452899cd76becb6a1c67c227.jpg).

I remember that a historical artifact also has protruding spikes, probably used by this martial arts duelist, but I can't find it on the web.